# jQuery {} array how do I reference/edit/update/remove etc etc

Tags: jquery, arrays, edit

consider the following:

```
 var service_call_array = { 
     3 : 'test',
     4 : 'more of a test eh?',
     5 : 'more info required'
 };
```

I can loop through it thus

```
$(function() { 
   $.each(service_call_array, function(key, value) {
        alert(key + ':' +value);
   }
});
```

but how in principle, I would add a fourth item key:value, how can I update or edit or change a value by key (say key:4) how can I remove by referencing the key, and how can I reference an elements value by the key without looping?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, that's an object - not an array. Arrays can only have numerical indices and have special semantics such as a `.length` property. Now, to answer your question.

What you have there is a plain old JavaScript object, and you're assigning properties on it. [MDN has a complete page about them.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) Here's a summary:

## Accessing properties

Use the `o.key` or `o["key"]` syntax, for example:

```
var object = {
    foo: "bar"
};
alert(object.foo); // displays "bar"
```

The `o["key"]` syntax is particularly handy when using the object as a lookup table, for example:

```
var translate = {
    "hello": "bonjour",
    "goodbye": "au revoir"
};
var word = "hello"; // received through some kind of user input
alert(translate[word]); // displays "bonjour"
```

## Setting properties

Similar to accessing properties, but now you place them on the left hand side of the assignment. It doesn't really matter whether the property already exists or not, it will be created if necessary.

```
var object = {};
object.foo = "bar";
alert(object.foo); // still "bar"
```

## Deleting properties

Use the `delete` statement.

```
var object = {
    foo: "bar"
}
alert(object.foo); // displays "bar"
delete object.foo;
alert(object.foo); // displays "undefined"
alert(object.foo === undefined); // displays true
```

Comment: thanks I just wanted to clarify the correct mechanism and notation.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're going to index with numbers, don't use an object `{}`, use an array `[]`.

Second, you **add** new items like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj.newItem = 'newItem';        // You can use the dot syntax when your member
                                // name is a valid identifier.
obj['new Item 2'] = 'newItem2'; // Or, you can use the bracket notation if it 
                                // isn't.

var arr = [];
arr[0] = 'firstItem';           // Use the bracket syntax.
arr[42] = 'anotherItem';        // The indices don't have to be contiguous.
```

To **access** or **update** a value, you would use similar syntax. All of the values are dynamic, so whether you're adding them for the first time or updating, it's syntactically the same:

```
var a = obj.newItem;            // Access with dot syntax
var b = obj['new Item 2'];      // Access with bracket syntax

obj.newItem = 'updatedValue'    // Update with new value using dot syntax
obj['new Item 2'] = 42          // Update with new value using bracket syntax
                                // Note that the type of the value doesn't have
                                // to remain the same.
```

To actually **delete** a value, use the `delete` keyword:

```
delete obj.newItem;             // Now, obj.newItem is undefined again.
```

Comment: the numbers are an irrelevancy, sorry for the confusion assume a key that is a text string

Answer (score 1):

You get a reference by calling `service_call_array.key` then you can update or do whatever you want with it.

Adding:

```
service_call_array.key = 'newValue';
service_call_array[key] =  'newValue';
```

Deleting:

```
delete service_call_array.key;
delete service_call_array[key];
```